# Evaluate rules in prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to convert the following decision rules to Prolog language

```
------Decision Rules---------
if (Right-Weight <= 2.5) and (Left-Weight > 2.5) and (Left-Distance > 1.5) then class: R (proba: 95.4%) | based on 87 samples
if (Right-Weight > 2.5) and (Right-Distance <= 2.5) and (Left-Weight > 1.5) then class: R (proba: 71.08%) | based on 83 samples
if (Right-Weight <= 2.5) and (Left-Weight <= 2.5) and (Left-Distance > 2.5) then class: R (proba: 63.41%) | based on 41 samples
if (Right-Weight > 2.5) and (Right-Distance > 2.5) and (Left-Weight > 2.5) then class: L (proba: 63.54%) | based on 96 samples
if (Right-Weight > 2.5) and (Right-Distance > 2.5) and (Left-Weight <= 2.5) then class: L (proba: 98.48%) | based on 66 samples
if (Right-Weight > 2.5) and (Right-Distance <= 2.5) and (Left-Weight <= 1.5) then class: L (proba: 77.78%) | based on 27 samples
if (Right-Weight <= 2.5) and (Left-Weight <= 2.5) and (Left-Distance <= 2.5) then class: L (proba: 65.22%) | based on 23 samples
if (Right-Weight <= 2.5) and (Left-Weight > 2.5) and (Left-Distance <= 1.5) then class: L (proba: 50.0%) | based on 14 samples
-----------------------------
```

Tried to come up with the following rules in prolog.

```
classR(Right-Weight, Left-Weight, Left-Distance) :- 
    (Right-Weight <= 2.5) , (Left-Weight > 2.5) , (Left-Distance > 1.5);
    (Right-Weight > 2.5) , (Right-Distance <= 2.5) , (Left-Weight > 1.5);
    (Right-Weight <= 2.5) , (Left-Weight <= 2.5) , (Left-Distance > 2.5)
   
classL(Right-Weight, Left-Weight, Left-Distance) :-
    (Right-Weight > 2.5) , (Right-Distance > 2.5) , (Left-Weight > 2.5);
    (Right-Weight > 2.5) , (Right-Distance > 2.5) , (Left-Weight <= 2.5);
    (Right-Weight > 2.5) , (Right-Distance <= 2.5) , (Left-Weight <= 1.5);
    (Right-Weight <= 2.5) , (Left-Weight <= 2.5) , (Left-Distance <= 2.5);
    (Right-Weight <= 2.5) , (Left-Weight > 2.5) , (Left-Distance <= 1.5)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
evaluate(RW, LW, LD, RD, OP) :- 
    ((RW =< 2.5),(LW > 2.5),(LD > 1.5) -> OP = 'R';
    (RW > 2.5) , (RD =< 2.5) , (LW > 1.5) -> OP = 'R';
    (RW =< 2.5) , (LW =< 2.5) , (LD > 2.5) -> OP = 'R';
    (RW > 2.5) , (RD > 2.5) , (LW > 2.5) -> OP = 'L';
    (RW > 2.5) , (RD > 2.5) , (LW =< 2.5) -> OP = 'L';
    (RW > 2.5) , (RD =< 2.5) , (LW =< 1.5) -> OP = 'L';
    (RW =< 2.5) , (LW =< 2.5) , (LD =< 2.5) -> OP = 'L';
    (RW =< 2.5) , (LW > 2.5) , (LD =< 1.5) -> OP = 'L').
```